# How to change level when all enemies are dead in a videogame?

Tags: java

I'm implementing a 2d videogame. When you kill all the enemies in a level you should go to the next level, but I don't know well how to implement it. Do you have any suggestions on the possible design patterns that I could use?

```java
public class GameWorld {
    int aliveEnemies = 3;

    void setAliveEnemies() {
        //omitted by OP
    }

    int getAliveEnemies() {
        if (aliveEnemies == 0) {
            goToNextLevel();
        }
    }
}



public class Level {
    void spawnEntities(){
        // omitted by OP
    }
}
```

Comment: Make a List of all enemies and objectives when the level starts.  When an enemy is killed, remove them from the list.  When the list is empty, the level is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your `Gameworld` has a `Level` attribute.
When you got to next level you should call the spawnEntity of your Level.

```java
public class GameWorld {
    Level currentLevel = null; //Level attribute
    int aliveEnemies = 0;

    //Gameworld constructor
    GameWorld(Level lev) {
        this.currentLevel = lev;
    }

    void setAliveEnemies() {
        this.aliveEnemies = this.currentLevel.spawnEntities(); //Load next enemies
    }

    int getAliveEnemies() {
        if (aliveEnemies == 0) {
            goToNextLevel();
        }
    }

    //goToNextLevel implementation
    private void goToNextLevel() {
        this.level = new Level(); //Load new Level
        this.setAliveEnemies(); // Load enemies of that level
    }
}



public class Level {
    int spawnEntities()  //should return number of enemis spawned
        // omitted by OP
        return 3;
    }
}
```